# startup batch file hangs up on second command

Tags: windows, batch-file

I created a startup bat file that looks like this

```
 taskkill /im RemoteDesktopManager.exe
 C:\Users\kheradmand\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
 "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PhpStorm 7.1.2\bin\PhpStorm.exe"
 "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
```

it does the first and second, but won't go any further, they all exist

how can I fix this?

update : I tried suggestion provided by @phd443322 and wrote this:

```
taskkill /im RemoteDesktopManager.exe
start "" /w C:\Users\kheradmand\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
start "" /w "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PhpStorm 7.1.2\bin\PhpStorm.exe"
start "" /w "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
```

intrestingly each command still waits for that program to be closed to continue to the next.

so why still not working?

Comment: can you put "start " in front of each .exe call? http://superuser.com/questions/413939/how-to-start-a-program-with-command-line-arguments-on-windows-cmd-with-start

Comment: Have you tried  phd443322 and Magoo's suggestion?

Comment: It waits because you told it to wait with the /w option.  So remove /w.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below there is a working Batch file, as first advised by phd443322:

```
taskkill /im RemoteDesktopManager.exe
start "" C:\Users\kheradmand\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PhpStorm 7.1.2\bin\PhpStorm.exe"
start "" "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
```

Comment: I read what he wrote but I couldn't figure out what to make of all that! so thanks for making it crystal clear

Comment: May I ask you to assign the bounty to this answer?

Comment: I would like to to that but the site says "You may award your bounty in 16 hours." !!

Comment: @Aacini This removes the lag in the execution. Thanks, but if you could explain why, that would be great. Because adding just `start "C:\..."` didn't solve the issue, but `start "" "C:\..."` did. why?

Answer (score 1):

Batch files wait for programs to exit unlike interactive. These are the rules documented in the Start command.

If Command Extensions are enabled, external command invocation
through the command line or the START command changes as follows:

non-executable files may be invoked through their file association just
by typing the name of the file as a command.  (e.g.  WORD.DOC would
launch the application associated with the .DOC file extension).
See the ASSOC and FTYPE commands for how to create these
associations from within a command script.

When executing an application that is a 32-bit GUI application, CMD.EXE
    does not wait for the application to terminate before returning to
    the command prompt.  This new behavior does NOT occur if executing
    within a command script.

When executing a command line whose first token is the string "CMD "
    without an extension or path qualifier, then "CMD" is replaced with
    the value of the COMSPEC variable.  This prevents picking up CMD.EXE
    from the current directory.

When executing a command line whose first token does NOT contain an
    extension, then CMD.EXE uses the value of the PATHEXT
    environment variable to determine which extensions to look for
    and in what order.  The default value for the PATHEXT variable
    is:

```
    .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD

Notice the syntax is the same as the PATH variable, with
semicolons separating the different elements.
```

When searching for an executable, if there is no match on any extension,
then looks to see if the name matches a directory name.  If it does, the
START command launches the Explorer on that path.  If done from the
command line, it is the equivalent to doing a CD /D to that path.

Comment: so for example how can I fix chrome?I want to make it run in my enviroment

Comment: `start "" /w chrome.exe` note start command is like Start - Run parsing so different rules to cmd normal executing. `start /?` for Help.

Comment: phd443322 ,@kenny I updated my answer, can you give me your thoughts on this?

Comment: Sorry, I was acting in reverse, remove the `/w`, that makes it wait. Start doesn't wait by default and cmd does in batch files for GUI progs.

Comment: What happened when you removed the `/w` from the `start` commands, as advised by  phd443322 ?